# Cocoa listening key events and responding them without view

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

First of all hi guys!
I was trying to write a mouse controller app for mac os x which is reading inputs from keyboard and moves the mouse accordingly. By garbage input i will describe the input was intented for a mouse event but it creates text on screen.

Before anyone points to the fact that there is a built in one, It was laggy even in shortest lag setting and cannot registers more than two buttons at the same time (you have to press diagonals to go to the diagonal.) If you accidentally press another button when release of the accident button your motion stops. My first and last reaction was "rubbish!". Adding customization and extra features is my goal.

I want to create a key combination that will block the garbage input to be passed to other programs while it was held. But global monitoring and seems like it always passes the event. And unfortunately I see qqqqqqqwwwwwww like text in unwanted places.

I want to see that when i press q w and up, it will make the mouse go up. But i create qqqqqqqwwwwww mess on the way. My first idea was creating a view on popover and handle events there, but whenever I want to use my mouse from keyboard seeing a popover is anoying and I couldn't find a way to show the popover without leaving any garbage keyboard input.

What should i do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [Quartz Event Taps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/). Note that for an application to tap keyboard events, it has to be trusted for accessibility (as in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility). Your app can ask to be made trusted using `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions()`.